# Javascript not resolving worker path relative to current script

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a script at `http://localhost/js/foo.js` which needs to spawn a Web Worker from the file `http://localhost/js/fooWorker.js`. I assumed I could just do something like this:

```
var worker = new Worker('fooWorker.js')
```

However, this results in a 404 error, as the browser cannot find `http://localhost/fooWorker.js`. I was under the impression that worker paths were resolved relative to the script spawning the worker, so shouldn't I just be able to specify the name of another .js file in the same directory without having to provide an absolute path? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_web_workers#Spawning_subworkers , this should work...

Comment: @ziesemer: The link you provided talks about sub-workers. These are not fully supported yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/:

> When the Worker(scriptURL) constructor is invoked, the user agent must
>   run the following steps:
>
> 1. Resolve the scriptURL argument relative to the **entry script's base**
>      URL, when the method is invoked.

Comment: Does anyone know how can base url be overriden when you instantiate a worker? Or are there some other practices how one can ship web workers in a lib?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it should be relative  to the embedded document path

For example,

I have

```
pathDoc\docA.html
js\b.js
js\worker\c.js
```

then code should be

```
var worker = new Worker('..\js\worker\c.js')
```

Comment: I tried this in a IIS hosted ASP.Net MVC app. But it didnt resolve the path. In the F12 network tab it shows 404. Any idea on IIS hosted sites

Answer (score 2):

Note, you can still get the script url within the worker using the [`self.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/location) and just prepend it to the paths to make them relative to the worker script rather than the html base url.

```js
const workerUrl = location + '';
const basePath = workerUrl.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '/');

self.importScripts(basePath + '/fooWorker.js');
```

Btw, if you include your worker via blob, you can still pass meta info like it's url via `#` hash params.

Comment: Why would you pass information through such an hacky way when you can postMessage it?

Comment: Weren't sure if `importScripts` can be called in a message listener. If it can, then sure, posting a message is also an option. Though that would be teensy bit slower I think.

Answer (score 2):

With *import.meta.url*, you should be able to have it work like relative path.

```
var worker = new Worker(new URL('./fooWorker.js', import.meta.url));
```